# pg_connect takes longer than 5 seconds?

Tags: php, postgresql, performance

I have just setup a OpenBSD little personal development server running PHP with an almost-default(enabled debugging messages) php.ini and installed PostgreSQL with the default configuration.

Well, running this very simple code

```
$starttimer=time()+microtime();

$dbconn = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=earlzblog_001 user=xxx password=xxx")
    or die("Couldn't Connect".pg_last_error());
pg_close($dbconn);
$stoptimer = time()+microtime();
echo "Generated in ".round($stoptimer-$starttimer,4)." s";
```

the result is "generated in 6.xxs. Why is it taking 6 seconds to simply make a database connection? Using PgAdmin3, the connections don't take any time at all.

Am I suppose to be using persistent connections here? Or unix-sockets or something?

Comment: In my experience, postgres connections *usually* take a millisecond at worst, but I've also seen them take up to a couple of seconds on a loaded server -- connection setup can take a little while: authorization, setting up buffers, etc.  If you're looking at high load, use a connection pool.

Comment: If you add another timing step between connecting and closing, does closing the connection take time as well?

Comment: no, closing the connection is almost instantaneous. Also, this database has literally zero load on it.

Comment: Turn on "log_connections" in the Postgres config (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHAT), restart, connect with pgAdmin, then with your script, check the log for differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this also happen if you

a) use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost
  b) use a unix socket

to connect to the postgresql server?
Is your OpenBSD, DNS, Postgresql server and/or php configured to use ipv6?

Comment: wow. I'm not sure why but using `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1` is what causes the major slow down... it is specific to PHP still though... and nothing was configured to use IPv6..

Comment: Just out of curiosity: What's the exact output (includeing error/warning messages) for `<?php echo inet_ntop(str_repeat(chr(0), 15).chr(1));` on your machine?

Answer (score 0):

Try, from the same machine, `telnet localhost 5432` to see if the problem is PostgreSQL-specific or not.

Comment: no, it's not postgres specific. as I said, pgadmin connects very quickly and doing that telnet thing connects very quickly.